# Xamarin.Forms Map automatically focuses on user location

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm creating a `Map` in Xamarin.Forms as follows:

```
var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(eventLoc, Distance.FromMiles(1)))
{
      IsShowingUser = true,
      MapType = MapType.Hybrid
};
```

Here, `eventLoc` is a `Position` on which I want my map should focus initially. Although it starts so, when location service finds my location, map focus goes to my location since I set `IsShowingUser = true`. However, this is not what I want. I'm writing `IsShowingUser = true` since I want to show my location on the map as well, but not focusing there.

How can I achieve to stay on the initial position (`eventLoc`) I provided to the map while showing my position as well?

Comment: `IsShowingUser` is a pretty poor feature, I would advise you to implement custom renderers if you want to be able to control the GPS/map interaction in a better fashion.

Comment: The `IsShowingUser` behavior on the Android device I am using to test `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` does not position the Map, it just enables the "blue dot" for current location and the go-to-current-location widget in the upper right corner. Not until I tap the widget does the map position to current location. Are you using Android or iOS?

Comment: No, WinPhone and UWP.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue of wanting to show the user's location but wanted the map to pan over to the destination pin. At the very end of `ContentPage.OnAppearing()` just move the map to where you want it to end up:

```
double someLatitude  = 0;
double someLongitude = 0;


VendorMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(someLatitude, someLongitude), Distance.FromMiles(25)));
```

Comment: Tried it, does not work since location service may find my location after 3-5 seconds later.

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim Then it sounds like you just need to run the code I posted after your location service finds your location. In my app, we gather the users location before they open the map page and then we move the map to the users location in the constructor (after `InitializeComponent()`). Then at the end of `OnAppearing()` we move the map again to show the destination. Though I have not tried any of that on windows devices.